# Longest hendecasyllable in Italian Literature

Tags: untagged

## 35 caratteri

I tre più famosi endecasillabi della lingua italiana, contando anche spazi e segni di interpunzione, sono lunghi

```
In [3]: [len(verso) for verso in '''Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita
   ...: mi ritrovai per una selva oscura,
   ...: ché la diritta via era smarrita.'''.split('\n')]
Out[3]: [35, 33, 32]
```

35, 33, e 32 caratteri.

Qual'è l'**endecasillabo** più lungo della letteratura italiana, conteggiando spazi e segni di interpunzione?

Le risposte valide devono contenere un riferimento all'autore ed all'opera, la risposta accettata sarà la prima a citare il verso più lungo.

Si raccomanda di intitolare la risposta con il numero di caratteri del verso.

---

PS "…" è un *singolo* carattere Unicode.

Comment: Domanda molto interessante, su cui ho un quesito e un'osservazione. 1) Visto che hai usato metodi informatici per contare i caratteri di quei tre versi, sei intanto in grado di dirci qual è l'endecasillabo più lungo della Commedia (o di qualche altro corpus più ampio, se lo hai)? 2) Nei testi più antichi, come appunto quelli di Dante, Petrarca etc., la grafia e la punteggiatura possono variare in modo significativo da un'edizione all'altra (“edizione” nel senso filologico). Quindi è possibile che la risposta sia “il verso [X] nell'edizione [Y]”.

Comment: Ah, e l'endecasillabo più breve?

Comment: @DaG Se scrivi una domanda "Qual è l'endecasillabo piú lungo della Commedia? e quale il piú breve?" sarò lieto di risponderti (spoiler "Dal centro al cerchio, e sì dal cerchio al centro"). Per corpi piú vasti, il problema è quello di normalizzare i testi, porta via molto tempo…

Comment: @DaG Lascia stare, rispondo qui sotto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 64 caratteri - *fior, fronde, erbe, aria, antri, onde, armi, archi, ombre, aura.*

È un verso di [Claudio Tolomei](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/claudio-tolomei), letterato e vescovo vissuto dal 1492 al 1556. Lo cita Giampaolo Dossena (lo sapevo che si era occupato anche di questo!) nel suo *Dizionario dei giochi con le parole* alla voce “Endecasillabo” (ripresa anche nell'*Enciclopedia dei giochi*), come possibile primatista in quanto  endecasillabo più lungo. Come accennavo in un commento, personalmente trovo più interessante considerare il solo numero di lettere, e così fa Dossena: 45 lettere.

Ovviamente Tolomei ci si era sbizzarrito di proposito, partendo da un verso del Petrarca (*fior, fronde, erbe, aria, antri, onde, aure soavi*) e sfruttando fino in fondo le possibilità offerte dalle sinalefe.

I successivi endecasillabi citati da Dossena sono :

> *quando egli ha il peggio e quando egli ha il migliore* (Boiardo; 43 lettere, 53 caratteri)

> *sia in giostra o sia in battaglia ogni altro eccede* (Tassoni; 42 l., 51 c.)

> *carta è il ciel, l'ombra inchiostro, e penna il raggio* (Marino; 42 l., 54 c.)

> *quantunque il mal, quanto può, accresce e impingua* (Ariosto; 41 l., 50 c.)

A quelli citati da Dossena aggiungo, con 51 caratteri e 43 lettere:

> *Tremando, e in fondo al verso rincantucciolanosene;*

È uno dei versi della famosa quartina scherzosa di Arrigo Boito, fatta di versi tetra- e pentasdruccioli:

> Sì crudo è il gelo che le rime sdrucciolanosene
> Tremando, e in fondo al verso rincantucciolanosene;
> Le gocciole d'inchiostro stalattitificanomisi
> Sotto la penna, ovvero stalagmitificanomisi.

Lì puntava appunto a massimizzare il numero di sillabe, e anzi è notevole che Dante ci vada vicino con onesti endecasillabi piani.

Comment: Devo procurarmi _Dizionario dei giochi con le parole_ e _Enciclopedia dei giochi_. Devo.

Comment: @PoldoSbaffini: Se ti interessano i giochi e iun particolare questo approccio ai giochi, di sicuro! :) Credo che il _Dizionario_ sia confluito interamente o quasi nell'_Enciclopedia_. Consiglio anche, quasi complementare, il _Dizionario dei giochi_ di Angiolino e Sidoti (Zanichelli, con un recente aggiornamento edito da Unicopli).

Answer (score 3):

### 49 caratteri — *Dal centro al cerchio, e sì dal cerchio al centro*

Un [commento](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/14248/longest-hendecasyllable-in-italian-literature#comment34813_14248) di [DaG](https://italian.stackexchange.com/users/37/dag) mi ha spinto a rispondermi da solo, limitando la risposta a quanto Dante ha scritto nella Commedia. @Dag, in fondo ci sono anche gli e.s. piú corti, ma non so quale sia il piú corto!

Il primo scoglio riguarda trovare una versione ".txt" con un alto rapporto segnale/rumore (segnale=endecasillabi, rumore=titoli, sottotitoli, introduzioni ai Canti, whatever). Forse non è un caso che [il testo che ho usato](https://dmf.unicatt.it/%7Edella/pythoncourse18/commedia.txt) sia distribuito nel contesto di un corso di programmazione.

Anche se il testo era in *buono stato*, andava comunque ripulito

- rimuovendo tutte le linee vuote
- rimuovendo tutte le intestazioni
- sostituendo il carattere "…" alla sequenza "..."

inoltre una ispezione dei risultati preliminari mostrava che alcune linee erano affette da

- sequenze di spazi di lunghezza non unitaria, p.e. "Pippo ␣ ␣ ␣ ␣ ␣ ␣ ␣ ␣ ␣ si taglia"
- virgole non seguite da spazio, p.e. "Pippo,cammina dritto"

Il programma di analisi (in linguaggio [Python](https://www.python.org/)) ed il suo output sono riportati in calce, qui mi preme di osservare che se per l'endecasillabo piú lungo credo si debba contare tutto, per l'endecasillabo più corto dovremmo forse contare solo spazi e lettere, e quindi `"O anima cortese mantoana,` vale per 24 caratteri.

---

Eseguendo

```
from re import sub
def quanti_caratteri_quante_lettere(verso):
    solo_lettere = sub(r'\W|\d', '', verso)
    return ((len(verso), verso),
            (len(solo_lettere), solo_lettere))

versi = []

for verso in open('commedia.txt').read().splitlines():
    if len(verso) < 22: continue      # titoli, etc non sono processati
    if ': Canto' in verso : continue  # alcuni titoli dei canti sono > 21
    verso = verso.strip()             # tolgo spazi a sx e a dx
    if '...' in verso :               # da 3 caratteri a 1 carattere
        verso = verso.replace('...', '…')
    verso = sub(' +', ' ', verso)              # da "        " a " "
    verso = sub(' ([^A-Za-z])', '\\1', verso)  # da " ," etc a ","
    verso = sub(',([^ ])', ', \\1', verso)     # da ",parola" a ", parola"
    versi.append(quanti_caratteri_quante_lettere(verso))

N = 6
versi.sort(key=lambda t:t[0])
print(*("%d %s"%lv[0] for lv in versi[:+N]), 
      '...',
      *("%d %s"%lv[0] for lv in versi[-N:]),
      sep='\n')
print('—'*72,)
versi.sort(key=lambda t: (t[1][0], t[0][0]))
print(*("%d %s"%(lv[1][0], lv[0][1]) for lv in versi[:+N]), 
      '...',
      *("%d %s"%(lv[1][0], lv[0][1]) for lv in versi[-N:]),
      sep='\n')
```

si avra`

```
25 Così la circulata melodia
25 Ivi così una cornice lega
25 O imaginativa che ne rube
25 ordine senta la religione
26 "O anima cortese mantoana,
26 Antigone, Deifile e Argia,
...
47 quai fuor li vostri antichi e quai fuor li anni
47 quell'altro foco? e chi son quei che'l fenno?".
47 se'l ciel li addolcia, o lo'nferno li attosca".
48 dal quinto il quarto, e poi dal sesto il quinto.
48 de l'altro; e s'elli avvien ch'io l'altro cassi,
49 Dal centro al cerchio, e sì dal cerchio al centro
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
20 così di Moisè come d'Elia,
20 e se rimane, dite come, poi
20 E io udi' ne la luce più dia
20 E"Ov'è ella?", sùbito diss'io.
20 or D, or I, or L in sue figure.
21 Ivi così una cornice lega
...
36 i occhi mi sciolse e disse:"Or drizza il nerbo
36 con li altri, innanzi a li altri aprì la canna,
36 da bocca il freddo, e da li occhi il cor tristo
37 dal quinto il quarto, e poi dal sesto il quinto.
38 quai fuor li vostri antichi e quai fuor li anni
39 Dal centro al cerchio, e sì dal cerchio al centro
```

Comment: Interessantissimo, grazie mille. Personalmente, per questo tipo di ricerche ludolinguistiche, conto le sole lettere (senza neppure gli spazi); ma ovviamente non c'è un motivo oggettivo per cui un criterio sia migliore di un altro. Con amici cercavamo il titolo italiano di film più lungo (appunto per numero di lettere) senza lettere ripetute. Un buon candidato è _Il grande scout_.

Comment: Per curiosità, secondo Dossena (vedi la mia risposta) l'endecasillabo più corto di Dante, contando solo le lettere, è «e “Ov'è ella?” subito diss'io» (20 lettere).

Comment: @DaG _Ov'è ella_ ma non solo. Ho migliorato(?) la risposta, includendo anche l'ordinamento per numero di lettere